# Part of the material doesn't disappear with Principled BSDF Alpha

Tags: node-editor, transparency

I'm a bit stumped on this one. I have an object made of merged particles with a material that makes them look like dust.

[image: Dust made with frozen/merged particles]

Despite my best efforts, I can't get the particles to fade out. My best attempt is this one :

[image: dust disappearing with the alpha of a principled BSDF]

Here is my node setup (everything before the second MixShader is essential for the effect, the rest is my attempt at transparency.

[image: Node setup for the material]

Sorry I can't show more of my window, I'm working on something confidential... If you need a screen of anything here, I'll provide it.

[image]

Comment: just make a simple object (like a sphere) with your material and put that in a blend file and provide that blend file. I assume the material isn't confidential!? sorry, but there are a lot of people out there who use the "confidential" and "copyright" thing just for their laziness....

Comment: I've added the .blend file with the dust effect and its problematic material : [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=12GMY7Ay" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/12GMY7Ay/). And of course it isn't confidential, I meant the whole file was. I'll keep in mind this solution next time I post here.

Comment: I think you need to increase the transmission or transparent Bounces in the Render properties > Light Paths > Max Bounces

Comment: That did it! Increasing the transparency bounces cleared up the black chunk of dust and now everything renders way better. Thank you!